# cat /dev/null > file.log does not truncate large file in Darwin

Tags: logs, darwin

In the past, on linux systems, I've been able to truncate large, open log files (that is, a file that is being actively written to by a process) using `cat /dev/null > file.log`.

However, on 10.9 (Mavericks), that doesn't seem to be the case. I've got an 11GB file that is being logged to by an application, but when I perform the same command with said file, nothing seems to happen.

When I try this on a file of trivial size, it does work.

Here is `ls -l /dev/null`:

`crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel    3,   2 Dec 16 12:49 /dev/null`

I've also tried `cp /dev/null file.log` to no avail.

Thinking that I might take advantage of the truncate function (`man 2 truncate` in Darwin) I compiled this and ran it against two files, one of trivial size and the other the actual log file. Again, it worked against the trivial file and did not work on the much larger log.

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2013 Thomas de Grivel <thomas@lowh.net>
 *
 * Permission to use, copy, modify, and distribute this software for any
 * purpose with or without fee is hereby granted, provided that the above
 ...
 * OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE USE OR PERFORMANCE OF THIS SOFTWARE.
 */

#include <unistd.h>

int main (int argc, const char **argv)
{
        int e = 0;
        while (--argc) {
                argv++;
                if (truncate(*argv, 0)) {
                        e = 4;
                        warn("%s", *argv);
                }
        }
        return e;
}
```

The process returns `0` regardless of which file I use.

Comment: How do you know it didn't work?  What does `du` or `du -h` say?  Is it possible the file is a sparse file?

Comment: Also, what's the purpose of including a license in this post?  It seems to be only adding noise.

Comment: `du -h /tmp/file.log` results in `11G    /tmp/file.log`

Comment: @Mikel I included the license as a courtesy...you'll note that I redacted most of it.

Comment: I love the way you removed everything in the licence below the word above (well nearly).

Comment: you could just `echo > /your/file`

Comment: It seems to me that all the user contributions are licensed under creative commons. I don't want to get sidetracked, but wouldn't CC take over in this case?

Comment: the license is a distraction, the true gem here is the answer

Comment: Related questions are https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/219197/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223878/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118219/ , and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/228092/ .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`cat /dev/null` is a bit convoluted a way to write a command that produces no output. `:` or `true` are more obvious ones.

In all of `cat /dev/null > file`, `: > file`, and even `> file` in most shells, the shell opens file with O_TRUNC on stdout, then runs the application which doesn't output anything, then the file is closed and left truncated.

However, in that case or when using the `truncate` system call, if the process that is filling up that file didn't open it with the O_APPEND flag, the next time it writes to the file descriptor it has open on the file, it will write the data at the offset it was within the file.

Because HFS+ doesn't support sparse files, that means that the space before that offset will  have to be reallocated and filled with zeros by the system.

So, you need to kill the application that is writing to that file before truncating it. Or you need to make sure the application opens the file with `O_APPEND` (like with `>>` if using shell redirection).

If you want to experiment with it:

```
$ exec 3> x
$ yes | head -n 50000 >&3
$ ls -ls x
200 -rw-r--r--  1 me me  100000 Dec 16 21:32 x
```

Now the fd 3 of my shell is 100000 bytes within the file

```
$ : > x
$ ls -ls x
0 -rw-r--r--  1 me me  0 Dec 16 21:34 x
```

Now the file is truncated (size 0, no space used on disk).

```
$ echo >&3
$ ls -ls x
200 -rw-r--r--  1 me me  100001 Dec 16 21:34 x
```

Writing 1 byte to the file at offset 100000, the file is now
100001 bytes large, the first ones all zeros, would use over 100k
on HFS+, but about just one disk block in most other Unix file systems

On the other hand, with:

```
$ exec 3>> x
$ yes | head -n 50000 >&3
$ ls -ls x
200 -rw-r--r--  1 me me  100000 Dec 16 21:35 x
$ : > x
$ echo >&3
$ ls -ls x
8 -rw-r--r--  1 me me  1 Dec 16 21:36 x
```

Writing 1 byte to the file not at offset 100000, but at the end of the file
because of `O_APPEND`. The file is 1 byte large, and takes the space needed
to hold that one byte.

Comment: I learned so much from this answer. Thanks.