# unix file is corrupted

Tags: files

I discovered that one of my logs consumes lots of space which comes from a running process. I wanted to clean this file, so I can run logadm to rotate it after. but I don't know how

```
# >MyLog_nohup.out
# ls -lLh MyLog_nohup.out
-rw-r-lr--   1 user     group       72G Jul 30 07:26 MyLog_nohup.out
# du -sh MyLog_nohup.out
480K   MyLog_nohup.out
```

Even after freeing it, still consumes 72G, and running more on it, just showing blank lines.. How can I fix that?

I can't afford restarting the process. But I wanted to use logadm to rotate this log file, is this possible? I tried, but it keeps coping blank lines an infinite loop. same as when I do more on this file. Is there any other way to fix this?

For logrotate, there is copytruncate option that deals with the open file, but I can't use it while the file has these blank lines as it runs in a loop.
I still don't understand why I can not view/more/head this file!

Comment: What is your application actually doing?

Comment: What really would you lose if you kill that process? It is buggy beyond the reasonable, so why do you want to keep it running? It is useless!

Comment: What are you really risking? Would you be killed (e.g. shot) or go to jail if you lose your process (I don't think so)? Why are you waiting till the disk is entirely fulled by useless log content?

Comment: [errare humanum est](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin_phrases_%28E%29#errare_humanum_est). But persisting your mistake is foolish.

Comment: As the last resort, you might give a try to attaching the process by gdb and close() the file descriptor in question.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/323180/4937930) for details.  I can never guarantee success!

Comment: This is why logging by redirecting `stdout` and/or `stderr` to a file is a **bad** idea.

Comment: Don't panic.  You probably *did* free 72GB of disk space when you truncated the file -- it's just that the logging process's idea of where it is in the file did not change, so now (as described in nkms's answer) you have 72GB of NUL bytes (which *don't* take up space on disk!) followed by the newest 420K of logs.   Does `df -h` tell you you have freed up space? If so, you can probably just leave everything as is.  `tail` should correctly show you the newest logs.

Comment: The irony of closing this as unreproducible is that people have regularly reproduced it before and since, and come here asking about it.  Including https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/502046/ just for starters.

Answer (score 5):

Your file is not corrupted; On Linux and POSIX systems, as long as a running process has an opened [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) to some file that it is writing, it will be able to continue writing it, even if you remove or rename that file (because a file descriptor is related to an [i-node](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode), not to a file name). in particular `logrotate` or `logadm` -or any sequence of external commands- won't do anything useful about the disk space.

<sup>I am assuming you are on Linux.</sup>

If your process has pid 1234, you could look into `/proc/1234/` in particular list the `/proc/1234/fd/` directory. Read [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html).

You probably should stop the offending process (using `kill -TERM` then `kill -QUIT` then at last `kill -KILL`; see [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) & [kill(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/kill.1.html)), then remove the file, and at last correct and/or configure your program to do some more useful logs, and start it again.

You probably have lost all the computation done by your program. So better stop it ASAP, improve it (perhaps you want some [application checkpointing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_checkpointing), or [persistence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_%28computer_science%29), or add some way to have it close, then rename, and then re-open the log file), and restart an improved version of your program.

You should read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/). You probably have several bugs in your program (perhaps related to logging). You might use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to understand the [syscalls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) done by your process, and you could use [syslog(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html) inside your (improved) program.

Very probably, you have a design bug in your program. So better stop it now, think, improve it, and start again. Waiting for the disk to be entirely filled won't help you (and it would make the matter worse).

For future testing purposes, you might consider setting some [disk quotas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_quota) and or some resource limits (e.g. [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html), and bash `ulimit` builtin).

In the future, always design your program to be able to afford restarting the process. Not being able to afford that is always a huge mistake (in particular, you need some backup strategy, and you need some [revision control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) on your source code; I recommend [git](http://git-scm.com/) for that).

Comment: I can't afford restarting the process. 
But I wanted to use logadm to rotate this log file, is this possible?
I tried, but it keeps coping blank lines an infinite loop. same as when I do more on this file.
Is there any other way to fix this?

Comment: Then you have lost all the computing done by that process. So just `kill -KILL` it right now. You lost it anyway!

Comment: I don't mind losing the logs contents for a period, but I can't kill this process... Any other solution?
Why does it shows this big size and empty blank lines in it

Comment: I don't see any solution outside of killing the process (you probably have some bug inside it related to logging). Then take a deep breath, read several good books on [Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/), think a few hours, improve the code, and start it again.

Comment: For logrotate, there is copytruncate option that deals with the open file, but I can't use it while the file has these blank lines as it runs in a loop

Comment: I believe you are mistaken. Why can't you kill your process, think for several hours, improve it, and start again... Your process is useless, so why do you keep it running?

Comment: I still don't understand why I can not view/more/head this file!

Comment: Read the links I gave you. They will explain that to you. Then think, take some sleep, and improve your buggy program, and restart again.

Comment: I am downvoting this answer because you are recommending a drastic action which is probably *not* necessary -- see nkms's answer and my comments there and on the question.

Answer (score 4):

```
# ls -lLh MyLog_nohup.out
-rw-r-lr--   1 user     group       72G Jul 30 07:26 MyLog_nohup.out
# du -sh MyLog_nohup.out
480K   MyLog_nohup.out
```

This looks like a sparse file to me. A sparse file allocates a virtual size on the disk (72G in your case) for efficiency but in reality the used space is as much data that is written on the file (480K in your case). The virtual size it's not calculated in the used space (you'll not free 72G in case you delete the file but only 480k).

You see blank lines when reading the file because... well there's only blank lines (nulls) in it. Try hexdump (1) to see the actual data (if any) but for any meaningful output you'll need a tool that understands the format of the file (the program creating the file should come with a tool for that).

Furthermore - as other have pointed out - you can't reclaim the resources of the file while the file remains mapped in memory. You need to free the mapping, that is ether terminate the program or you could try this with gdb (1)

```
pidof <procname>       # find the pid of the process which creates the log file
ls -l /proc/<pid>/fd/  # find the fd pointing to MyLog_nohup.out
gdb -p <pid>           # attach to pid
(gdb) p close(<fd>)    # close fd pointing to log file
```

However please note that the program might recreate the log file or have an unspecified behaviour when the fd closes and since you 'can't afford restarting the process' the above might be just too risky, just let the log file be.

Comment: I suspect what's happened is, truncating the file from the shell *did* release 72GB of space, but *didn't* change the logging process's offset in the still-open file -- so there are now 72GB of virtual NULs followed by 480K of normal logs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that.
I know That there is data in it by tailing it... just was curious for having these NULLs in the begining. I did many small nohup before, and this is the first time to notice that.
My point here is to use logadm for rotation, but I can't because of this NULLs

Comment: @asa: if you are worried about filling up your disk then just continue to run `>MyLog_nohup.out` every day or whenever `du` says  the file is too big.  If you want to save the output of `MyLog_nohup.out`, you're going to have to write a tricky script to ignore or skip all the nulls at the beginning of the file before you run `>...`

Comment: @asa: The reason why logadm for rotation does not work is that your program was not written to support that. The reason your file has NULLs at the start is because you ran `>MyLog_nohup.out` and your program does not have the file opened in APPEND mode.