# Clearing the content of files by size

Tags: shell, find

Considering if I list files in a directory:

```
drwx--x--x 43 root wheel 4.0K Aug 18 12:52 ..
-rw-------  1 root root  268K Aug 18 04:31 build_locale_databases_log
-rw-------  1 root root  5.2M Aug 18 17:21 access_log
-rw-------  1 root root   85K Aug 18 17:14 cpbackup_transporter.log
-rw-------  1 root root  2.1M Aug 18 05:49 cphulkd.log
-rw-------  1 root root  3.2M Aug 18 17:19 error_log
-rw-------  1 root root  1.7M Aug 18 12:52 license_log
```

Here I want to clear the contents of the files which are greater than `2Mb`. (i.e) to make the file size to zero bytes for the following files:

```
access_log
cphulkd.log
error_log
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I came up with:

```
find . -type f -size '+2M' -print | while read i
do
echo " " > $i
done
```

which works.

Comment: which *doesn't* work. It writes two bytes in the file. Use `: >"$i"` to truncate the file to 0 bytes. Using `-print | while read` only works for file names that don't contain special characters, you should use `find -exec …` or `find … -print0 | xargs -0` instead.

Comment: Its working well for me, it makes the file size to zero byte @Gilles

Answer (score 5):

I like to answer the direct question first, but **do not run this before reading to the end of my answer**.  The command you are asking for (which may not be what you want) is:

```
find /wherever -type f -name '*.log' -size +4096 -print \
    | xargs truncate --size 0
```

Note that the +4096 means files with more than 4096 512-byte sectors.  The problem is that if these are log files that a process is actively writing to, those processes will keep their position in the file.  You'll recover the disk space (assuming your file system supports sparse files, which most do), but when you go to look at your logs there will be blocks of zeros at the beginning.  So you really need to restart your daemon right after doing this, or better yet move the files out of the way and restart your daemons:

```
cd /wherever
find . -name '*.log' -maxdepth 1 -size +4096 -exec mv {} {}.old \;
systemctl restart yourservice (or whatever you need to restart)
rm -f *.old
```

Comment: "_those processes will keep their position in the file_" - are you sure?  I've just tested, using `exec 3>>foo; echo test test >&3; cat foo; : >foo; echo bam bam >&3; cat foo`, and the same with `>` instead of `>>`; in both cases the write position was correctly reset to the new end of file.

Comment: Depends if file opened with O_APPEND or not. If not, then truncating file does not affect seek pointers.

Comment: On linux 4.1.5, if I run `yes > mylogfile & sleep 1; :>mylogfile; kill %yes` and look at `mylogfile` with `hexdump`, there are tons of 0-valued bytes at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Ah, you're right (and I can repro that with my earlier approach if I write more than a single block - e.g. `exec 3>mylogfile; timeout 0.1 yes >&3; ls -log mylogfile; :>mylogfile; ls -log mylogfile; echo >&3; ls -log mylogfile`).  And `exec 3>>mylogfile` behaves.

Comment: `find /data -type f -size +5G -exec truncate -s0 {} \;` in general.  Specifically to the OP question: `find /data -type f -name '*log' -size +2M -exec truncate -s0 {} \;`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by a find command:

```
for i in $(find . -type f -size +2097152c);do  cat /dev/null > $i;done
```

The find command `find . -type f -size +2097152c` will find all files of size greater than

> 2MB (2097152 bytes)

The for loop will loop into the list of the files it got in the find command and will clean them out with a `cat /dev/null`

**------Edit------**

As suggested by  user3188445 You can try this way also

```
for i in $(find . -type f -size +2097152c);do  :  > $i;done
```

Comment: This is more complicated than necessary.  Note that the shell built-in `:` or the `true` command is better than `cat /dev/null`.

Comment: Note that this won't work with file contain newline, and will empty all files in current directory if filename contain ` * `.

Comment: Also, if you are using IFS anyway why not `truncate --size 0 $(find . -type f -size +2097152c)`?

Answer (score 0):

Posixly:

```
find . ! -name . -prune -type f -size +2097152c -exec sh -c '
  for f do
    : > "$f"
  done
' sh {} +
```

With GNU find or BSD find:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -size +2M ...
```

Comment: It returns the error        "find: missing argument to `-exec'"

Comment: @LeslinJea: What command did you run exactly? Do you copy paste or typing by your self?

Answer (score 0):

```
while read -r line; do
    truncate -s 0 $line
done < <(find / -type f -name '*.log' -size +2M)
```